# Easiest way to get most recent element of a running RxJava (1.x) Observable (blocking)

Tags: rx-java

How can I get the most recent element from an active Observable without waiting for it to complete? I realise this will need to be a blocking method, and this is OK. All I can find is `mostRecent()` and `next()` but these return Iterables instead of the actual elements. It is not clear to me what the semantics of the iterables are here. I just want to get the element. Why is this made so hard?

Comment: Have you looked at [blocking `first()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html#first--)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `doOnNext()` operator to perform an operation on an emitted valued. For instance:

```
AtomicReference<Integer> sample = new AtomicReference<>();

...
.doOnNext( value -> sample.set( value ) )
...
```

So, `value` will have the most recent value that was emitted.